# Custom Segue back button crashes app

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I've written a custom segue for my app that partially obscures the source view controller. The segue works fine, and I get the desired effect. When I press the button to unwind the segue back to the source controller, the app crashes. I put some log statements in various methods but nothing is called, so I think I've wired up the views wrong. Here's the segue code:

```
- (void)perform {
NSLog(@"performing!");
UIView *sourceView = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController).view;
UIView *destView = ((UIViewController *)self.destinationViewController).view;
UIViewController *sourceController = ((UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController);

if (!_rewinding) {
[sourceView.window insertSubview:destView aboveSubview:sourceView];
    destView.center = CGPointMake(sourceView.frame.size.width * 1.5, sourceView.center.y);
}

CGPoint newSourceCenter = CGPointMake(sourceView.frame.origin.x - sourceView.frame.size.width * 0.4, sourceView.center.y);
CGPoint newDestCenter = CGPointMake(sourceView.center.x + sourceView.frame.size.width * 0.1, sourceView.center.y);


[UIView animateWithDuration:1.4
                 animations:^{
                     if (_rewinding) {
                         NSLog(@"rewind in segu");
                         destView.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, destView.center.y);
                         sourceView.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*1.5, sourceView.center.y);
                         destView.alpha = 1.0;
                     } else {
                         destView.center = newDestCenter;
                         sourceView.center = newSourceCenter;
                         sourceView.alpha = 0.5;
                     }
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (_rewinding)
                     NSLog(@"completed animation");
                 }];
}
```

A couple pictures to show what happens. On tapping a cell, the detail view slides left from the right off screen and the source view slides left as well.

[image: main/source view]   [image: after segue]

I've tried using `[source presentViewController:dest]` but doing that removes the source view from the window. Since I'm partially obscuring the source, it has to stay on the screen after animation. What's the right way to set this up?

Edit:
With zombies enabled, I got this in the log. That corresponds to the destinationViewController. So it's clear it isn't being retained during the segue.

```
[58880:c07] *** -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1f3c7fe0
```

Comment: What is the exact crash? Can you post the symbolicated crash log?

Comment: @RoboticCat Crash might not have been the right word to use. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm working on getting a log of what happens.

Comment: To be clear: you are saying that 0x1f3c7fe0 corresponds to a previous view controller instance you are unwinding to? I would be amazed if a view controller had been deallocated but if that's the case, I'm not sure how to hunt down this bug.

Comment: When perform is called, I logged the source and dest view controllers. Once I press the done button, the app halts. The zombie log statement has that memory address which corresponds to the destination view controller. Somehow the way I am adding that view is causing the view controller not to be retained and so it gets dealloc'd. Moreover I'm not sure how to add the view and the controller the right way.

Comment: Well, I suppose if it's being deallocated then the app is not holding a strong reference to it anywhere.  Can you add a strong reference to the view / view controller and then make sure it is nilled out after the unwind has occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer this with what I ended up doing, but leave it open because I'm earnestly interested in a way to do a segue that leaves part of the original view on screen.

My quick solution was to just handle the animation all within the originating view controller. I think this covers all the memory related issue above, but it may not be correct so use at your own risk.

```
- (void)showModalDetailView {
NSLog(@"show modal");
if (!self.detailViewController) {
    self.detailViewController = (SegmentDetailViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segDetail"];
    self.detailViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 1.5, self.view.center.y);
    [self.view.superview addSubview:self.detailViewController.view];
    self.detailViewController.delegate = self;
}

CGPoint newSourceCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x - self.view.frame.size.width * 0.4, self.view.center.y);
CGPoint newDestCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x + self.view.frame.size.width * 0.1, self.view.center.y);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.4
                 animations:^{
                     if (self.shouldRewind) {
                         self.view.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, self.view.center.y);
                         self.detailViewController.view.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width*1.5, self.detailViewController.view.center.y);
                         self.view.alpha = 1.0;
                         self.shouldRewind = NO;
                         self.detailViewController = nil;
                     } else {
                         self.detailViewController.view.center = newDestCenter;
                         self.view.center = newSourceCenter;
                         self.view.alpha = 0.5;
                         self.shouldRewind = YES;
                     }
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"animation complete");

                 }];

}
```